# Interpolation in R

Tags: r, interpolation

I have hourly time series and would like to interpolate sub-hourly values like every 15 min. Linear interpolation will do. But if there is any way to specify Gaussian, Polynomial, that would be great.

For example if I have

a<-c(4.5,7,3.3) which is the first three hour data. How can I get 15 min sub-hourly data, total of 9 values in this case? I have been using approx function and studying zoo package and still don't know how I can do it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Right now your question is too vague, and the best answer is probably to google for `R interpolate timeseries`. You need to come up with a reproducible example, including code and data, and a concrete question.

Comment: Similar question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4043/averaging-time-series-with-different-sampling-interval

Comment: This really feels more like a Mathematics questions than a StackOverflow question.  Linear interpolation can be defined as `f(x1, y1, x2, y2, xN) = y1 + (xN-x1) * (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`, which returns the y-value corresponding to xN, where point 1 is located at (x1, y1), and point 2 is located at (x2, y2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `xts` package, you can either `na.approx` or  `na.spline`.

1. Coerce you times series to an `xts` object
2. Create a new index having 15 minutes intervals
3. Use this new index to create a NULL xts object that you merge with your object
4. Approximate missing values using `na.approx` for linear/constant approx or `na.spline` for polynomial one.

here a complete example:

```
library(xts)
set.seed(21)
## you create the xts object
x <- xts(rnorm(10),
         seq(from=as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()),
             length.out=10,
             by=as.difftime(1,units='hours')))
## new index to be used 
new.index <- 
  seq(min(index(x)),max(index(x)), by=as.difftime(15,units='mins'))
## linear approx
na.approx(merge(x,xts(NULL,new.index)))
## polynomial approx
na.spline(merge(x,xts(NULL,new.index)))
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
b<-xts(c(4.5,7,3.3), order.by=as.POSIXct(c('2013-07-26 0:00', 
                                           '2013-07-26 2:00', 
                                           '2013-07-26 3:00')))
approx(b, n=13)   ,
```

adjusting `n` for the appropriate time interval?