# How to create a mathematical function from data plots

Tags: r, function, chemistry

I am by no means a math person, but I am really trying to figure out how create a graphable function from some data plots I measure from a chemical titration. I have been trying to learn R and I would like to know if anyone can explain to me or point me to a guide to create a mathmatic function of the titration graph below. 
Thanks in advance.
[image: mL Base V Acid Solution]

Comment: Chemistry isn't my area, but it looks like a logistic curve. Google search turns up a lot of hits on "chemical titration" and "logistic", so I think that this is a reasonable guess (though doubtless an oversimplification). You could search for how to do logistic regression in R.

Comment: You want to fit a model. This can be a logistic curve (parametric) or fit something more flexible, a non parametric curve, like a spline as mentioned by @user1774806.

Comment: Downvote for failing to search: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/titrationCurves/vignettes/titrationCurves.pdf

Comment: I looked at the documentation and installed the package for titrationCurves, it only builds models it doesn't create functions from data

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is a **Interpolation**. I'm *not* a R programmer, but I'll try to answer anyway.

Some of the more common ways to achieve this function you want is by **Polynomial Interpolation** which usually gives back a *Nth* degree polynomial function, where N is the number of data points minus one (1 point gives a constant, 2 points make a line, 3 makes *a*x^2 + b*x + c* and so on).

Other common alternatives I've learn are used in Computer Graphics are **Splines**, **B-spline**, **Bézier curve** and **Hermite interpolation**. Those make the curve *smoother and good looking* (I've told they originated in the car industry so they are less true to the data points).

**TL;DR:** I've found evidence that there is a implementation of **spline** in R from the question [Interpolation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885155/interpolation-in-r#17885618) which may lead you to your solution.

Hope you get to know better your tool and do a great work.

---

When doing this kind of work in Computer Science we call it **Numerical Methods** (at least here in my university), I've done some class and homework in this area while attending to the Numerical Methods Course (it can be found at [github](https://github.com/luis-puhl/metodos-numericos/tree/master/T4-Interpolacao)) but it's nothing worth noting.

I would add a lot of links to Wikipedia but StackOverflow didn't allow it.

Comment: This is a) too vague for SO. (no code), and b) not suggesting the known form of titration curves.

Comment: You should have voted to close and cited a relevant reference, such as https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/titrationCurves/vignettes/titrationCurves.pdf